# Accessing the Local System Account to accept a software licence

Tags: windows-server-2008, coldfusion, licensing, accounts

I have a server at the moment running ColdFusion which is being used to access a windows whois program on the server. Each time I call this command via ColdFusion (using cfexecute) the command times out. I believe the issue is because the first time a user runs the .exe file they are asked to accept the licence. ColdFusion is currently set to run under the Local System account and I am just wondering if it is possible to somehow log into this account and run the program manually via the console so that I can accept the licence.

I guess my only other option is to change the account ColdFusion runs under, but I would rather not do this.

Answer (score 1):

In cases like this I generally just run the main ColdFusion Application service as a particular user and then log into the server with that user account to unlock the software, accept the terms, download the SFTP key, etc. so that ColdFusion can use it as that user.  The Adobe ColdFusion lockdown guide actually recommends running ColdFusion under its own low-privilege account which has access to as little as possible on the server.